# How to move a function from one Kotlin class to another using IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, refactoring

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA to refactor some Kotlin code. I have two classes in the same file and I want to move a function from one class to another using Refactor -> Move (F6), but that doesn't work, and I get [tooltip message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BiPN.png)  that says: "Cannot perform refactoring. Move declaration is only supported for top-level declarations and nested classes". 
Am I doing something wrong? Or that refactoring is simply not supported?

[edit1] I tried to do the same operation with Java classes and everything works perfectly; so why this is not allowed for Kotlin?

[edit2] I thought that the problem is only when to two classes are in the same file, but it turns out that is not possible to move a function between classes in separate files!

Comment: See the request which you can vote for: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-23708

Comment: I think it's pretty awkward that being Kotlin the language being created and actively promoted by JetBrains, they haven't been able to make this kind of basic features (refactoring is a must for any software project) compatible with the language they've created :(

Answer (score 5):

It's a well-known Kotlin-only problem.

- in IDEA (both free and paid editions);
- in Android Studio.

[Official ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-23708)

Comment: Apparently, as of version 1.4, this problem is still existing :/

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy, but slightly janky, work around.

You just need to wrap the function you want to move in a class:

```
class TopLevelClass {
    fun functionToMove() {
        //...
    }
}
```

wrap it in a new class

```
class TopLevelClass {
    class TemporaryMoveClass{ /** you can now move this entire new class */
        fun functionToMove() {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

and after you do the refactor, delete the temporary wrapper class you created.

The janky part is that you need to replace all instances of `functionToMove()` with `NewTopLevelClass.functionToMove()` yourself.

One of the major benefits of doing it this way, rather than just cut and pasting it yourself, is that as soon as you wrap it in the `TemporaryMoveClass` it will tell you any parameters you need to introduce(Refactor>Extract>Parameter). And then you can do that inside the original `TopLevelClass` before you move it. (this preserves the types of any `TopLevelClass` properties you were using, and automatically introduces the new parameter(s) into the existing function calls)